# Extracting a zipped directory into external storage

Tags: java, android, java-io

I zipped a directory called dir2 that contains some text files.  I want to create a directory in external storage called dir that holds dir2.

Given a zipped dir2, I am trying to extract so it looks like:
external_storage_path/dir/dir2/textfile.txt

```
createFile(zis, "dir2/textfile.txt");

private void createFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filename) {
if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        boolean created = false;
        File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                        "dir/dir2/textfile.txt");
        if(!newFile.exists()) {
            // create the file and any parent dirs if needed
            created = newFile.mkdirs();
        }

        if(created) {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
                fnf.printStackTrace();
            }
```

An exception is thrown when trying to create the BufferedOutputStream:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  
/storage/emulated/0/dir/dir2/textfile.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a 
directory)
```

The textfile is not a directory though.

Comment: why are you creating a folder (directory) like this: `/storage/emulated/0/dir/dir2/textfile.txt` ?

Comment: i am trying to create dir/dir2/textfile.txt in external storage

Comment: i know, but why are you creating a folder (directory) like this: `/storage/emulated/0/dir/dir2/textfile.txt` ?